# How to save user input data on swiping the page of a PageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a pageViewController consisting of three pages namely (VC1,VC2,VC3), these are basically test forms that a user needs to fill, so they consist out of  textfields and radio buttons.

After entering the data,there's a button on the last page of the PageViewController i.e VC3, which directs the user to a view controller that displays the data entered on the pages, but I'm only getting the data of VC3 as that is the ViewController with the button. I want to get the data entered by the user on all the three pages of the PageViewController without creating a button on each of them.

In other words, I want to display the data of all tree pages by clicking on this button which is on the third page i.e VC3 or is there a way where I can save the user input data by swiping the page of a pageviewcontroller?

Could you please help me with a solution regarding the same problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add your code in your question post to supplement your question. By only describing your code, it is much harder for us to provide help...

Comment: In iOS there are lots of means to pass data between ViewControllers. The chosen one will depend on your architecture. [Here](https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/) are the most commons ways to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple method is to save all the user input data in each page using UserDefaults and you can access these saved user defaults in a view controller that displays the data entered on the pages and display it in that view controller.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(username, forKey: "UserName")
UserDefaults.standard.set(gender, forKey: "Gender")
```

and so on and you can get/access these as below:

```
let username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "UserName")
let gender = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Gender")
```